# How to trigger facebook messenger with a button

Tags: angular

My website is built with angular 6, In the site, I got a button and a facebook messenger chat. I want when I click the button, the facebook chat will open and focus cursor

Some thing like this. Is it possible?

This is my code, in **app.module.ts**

```js
import { FacebookModule } from ‘ngx-facebook’;

imports: [
   // other imports   
  FacebookModule.forRoot()
],
```

In document head I got this

```js
<script type=”text/javascript”     src=”https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js"></script>
```

In **app.components.ts**

```js
import { FacebookService, InitParams } from ‘ngx-facebook’;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private facebookService: FacebookService) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.initFacebookService();
    }
    private initFacebookService(): void {
      const initParams: InitParams = { xfbml:true, version:‘v3.2’};
      this.facebookService.init(initParams);
    }
}
```

and in index.html

```js
<div class="fb-customerchat" attribution=setup_tool page_id="1234131234" theme_color="#1ea1d9"
        >
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but you should provide some code and describe a more specific issue here. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Put this anywhere you want, FB is available globally

```js
somethingclick(){
  FB.CustomerChat.showDialog()
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Is this from the official docs?
EDIT: my bad, actually it worked!